# Improving the performance of file search and MediadataRetriever

Tags: java, android, optimization

I have an Array of files and want to get an ArrayList which only contains the audiofiles from said Array.
I was wondering if there is a way to improve the performance of my code (Right now it takes about 85 seconds to iterate through 14000 files).

My Code:

```
final File[] ArrayOfFiles = mysteriousFunction(); //returns a ton of files
final MediaMetadataRetriever iLoveThisThing = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

ArrayList<File> audioFiles = new ArrayList<>();

for (File file : ArrayOfFiles)
            {
                final String fileString = file.toString();

                String extension = "";
                final int lastIndexOfDot = fileString.lastIndexOf('.');
                final int lastIndexOfSeperator = fileString.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
                if (lastIndexOfDot > lastIndexOfSeperator)
                {
                    extension = fileString.substring(lastIndexOfDot + 1);

                }

                switch (extension)
                {
                    case "mp3":
                    case "mp4":
                    case "3gp":
                    case "m4a":
                    case "aac":
                    case "ogg":
                    case "wav":
                    case "mid":
                    case "ts":
                    case "imy":
                    case "flac":
                    case "xmf":
                    case "mxmf":
                    case "mkv":
                        iLoveThisThing.setDataSource(fileString);
                        final String foo1 = iLoveThisThing.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE);
                        if (foo1 != null)
                        {
                            String foo2 = foo1.substring(0, foo1.indexOf('/'));
                            if (foo2.equals("audio"))
                            {
                                audioFiles.add(file);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
```

> I have received quite a few tips already, so here's my updated code:

```
private static final Set<String> extensions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("mp3", "mp4", "3gp", "m4a", "aac", "ogg", "wav", "mid", "ts", "imy", "flac", "xmf", "mxmf", "mkv"));

public static void DoStuff()
{
    new Thread(() -> {
        final File[] allFiles = get_a_ton_of_files();
        final Set<File> audioFilesSet = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet(allFiles.length);
        Arrays.stream(allFiles).parallel().forEach(file -> {
            final String fileString = file.toString();
            final int lastIndexOfDot = fileString.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (lastIndexOfDot > fileString.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar))
            {
                final String extension = fileString.substring(lastIndexOfDot + 1);
                if (extensions.contains(extension))
                {
                    final MediaMetadataRetriever myMediadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                    myMediadataRetriever.setDataSource(fileString);
                    final String mime = myMediadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE);
                    if (mime != null && mime.startsWith("audio"))
                    {
                        audioFiles.add(file);
                    }
                    myMediadataRetriever.release();
                }
            }
        });
    }).start();
}
```

> Any further optimizations are obviously still highly appreciated.

Comment: Where did the list of files come from? Most likely the slow part of the program is the one that reads from file system. Also, what does this "extractMetadata" function do?

Comment: You could improve it by not checking for extensions because you are checking for the MIME type anyway, so why not just go ahead and check the MIME type already?

Comment: Dont do this task in the main thread do it in async task it will take less time

Comment: If the device has four cores then start eight threads who handle each 1/8 of the list.

Comment: But who delivers you 140000 File objects? You should tell the retriever which files you want.

Comment: @Joni I used System.currentTimeMillis() to determine which part of the programm was slow. Getting the files takes about 5 sec which is fine, but processing all of them in this loop takes 85, so the problem definelty lies here.

extractMetadata is a function of MediaMetadataRetriever which allows to acces many details about files. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#extractmetadata)

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava I am already executing this in a different thread.

Comment: @greenapps Aaah good thing you said that. I unintentionally got a zero too much. I'll fix that.
Anyway, reducing the number of files is sadly not possible.

Comment: @Dummy Only checking for MIME could result in audio files that are not of one of the listed types. wma would be an example of an audiofile which i don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are something you can do to improve your speed:

1. `for (File file : ArrayOfFiles)` can be executed in parallel
2. Don't use `MediaMetadataRetriever`. It's time consuming.

> Call this method before the rest of the methods in this class. This method may be time-consuming.

You can use `ContentResolver` instead.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
String mime = contentResolver.getType(uri);
```

Put it in action:

```
Set<File> audioFileSet = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet(ArrayOfFiles.length);

Set<String> ext = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("mp3", "mp4", ...));

ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

Arrays.stream(ArrayOfFiles).parallel().forEach(file -> {
    String extension = ...;
    if (ext.contains(extension)) {
        String mime = contentResolver.getType(Uri.fromFile(file));
        ...
        audioFileSet.add(file);
    }
});

// If you want list:
List<File> list = new ArrayList<>(audioFileSet);
```

If using `MediaMetadataRetriever`:

```
Arrays.stream(ArrayOfFiles).parallel().forEach(file -> {
    String extension = ...;
    if (ext.contains(extension)) {
        // Must init in side loop
        MediaMetadataRetriever iLoveThisThing = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        iLoveThisThing.setDataSource(fileString);
        String mime = iLoveThisThing.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE);
        ...
        audioFileSet.add(file);
        // Dont forget to release resource:
        iLoveThisThing.release();
    }
});
```

Comment: The Sets are great at speeding up things (they save about 10 seconds compared to ArrayLists), however, the contentResolver always returns null. This happens because getType only works for content uris (content://) and not for file uris (file://).

Comment: After some testing i discovered a really weird bug: if i run the stream parallel, some files suddenly pass the mimi-type check (some videos/applications/anything make it in the audioFileSet, despite me checking it with mime.startsWith("audio"))
The exact same code does not have this bug when run sequentially. Also the falsely added files are different each time i debug it.

Comment: I think i found the culprit: setDataSource(fileString); doesn't work well with parallel streams

Comment: If you use "MediaMetadataRetriever" then you have to init it inside the .forEach, or yoy"ll end up with concuurency problem

Comment: I had already implemented everything as you descripe it, but another bug occured. For some reason too little entries end up in the ArrayList audioFiles. See edited question for details.

Comment: Here is the problem: `final ArrayList<File> audioFiles = new ArrayList<>();`. See how I used my concurrent set. `Set<File> audioFileSet = ...`. When parallel execution, some entry is lost when add to list because you're using a normal container, not a `concurrent` one. Do exactly as my suggested code

Comment: Using the Set instead of an ArrayList it now works like a charm.. and the processing time was at least halfed! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It would better to check whether a file is an audio file using this approach:

```
public static boolean isMediaFile(String filepath) {
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(filepath);
    return mimeType != null && mimeType.startsWith("audio");
}
```

So you don't even need to use Switch-Case statement. Just try it:

```
if (isMediaFile(file.getAbsolutePath()) {
    audioFiles.add(file);
}
```